# Morpheme breakdown of the word 'classification'

Tags: syntax, morphology

For the word classification, would it break down to 'class-ify-ation' or 'class-ify-ic-ation'. I am confused between the two because for the second one, classific isn't a word.

Comment: When doing a morphological analysis, it's always important to decide if it's going to be synchronic or diachronic. The results could be very different.

Answer (score 2):

Well Nicholas, depending on your point of view, you were either very lucky or unlucky to choose the word *classification*.

> I am confused between the two because for the second one, classific isn't a word.

You're right, it isn't. Here's how I would break down `classification`:

> `class`-`ify`-`[c]ation`

> `root`-`suffix`-`suffix`

---

You see, although the final suffix is `-ation`, a `c` is inserted to produce `-cation`. This is a type of [sound change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_change) and this phenomena is more commonly known as [epenthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis).

It can occur when there is *friction* between the end of stem and the initial sound of the following suffix.

Just try saying `classify`-`ation`. Classifyaytion? Classifiation?

So, as a [general rule](http://wordstudyresources.benchmarkeducation.com/pdfs/1_K3_U17_BLM.pdf), stems ending in y are transformed:

- The y becomes an i.
- the head of the `-ation` suffix receives a `c`, becoming `-cation`.

---

Now as for how to treat the sound change, there isn't really an agreed upon convention. In fact, that link from above treats `-ation` and `-cation` as distinct suffixes. So it's kind of up to you.

You could ignore the emergence of the c if you are insistent on doing a more canonical breakdown:

> `class`-`ify`-`ation`

Or you could match the spelling:

> `class`-`ifi`-`cation`

*Or* you could do as I did and mark the `[c]` as a part of the final suffix and not a suffix in its own right:

> `class`-`ify`-`[c]ation`

It's entirely up to you.